# i try to understand initializers in obj-c and i can't

Tags: objective-c, class, import, initialization

I try to understand how to work simple init funcion and I don't know where I have made a mistake. Can somebody assist?

Rectangle.h

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject
{
    int width;
    int height;
}
-(id)initObject;
@end
```

Rectangle.m

```
@implementation Rectangle

-(id)initObject{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        height = 5;
        width = 7;
    }
    return self;
}    

@end
```

And in ViewController.h i import Rectangle.h, declare *rect object and in .m i execute(? run?) initObject.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Rectangle.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    Rectangle *rect;
}
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    rect = [[Rectangle alloc] initObject];
    NSLog(@"%@", rect);

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

initObject return me:

```
 2011-11-21 09:43:02.625 initializers[43693:f803] <Rectangle: 0x6ab1660>
```

Comment: why this "if (self = [super init]) {?"

Comment: There is no problem, looks fine. If you want to see `height` and `width` write `NSLog(@"%d, %d", rect.height, rect.width);`

Comment: i see in many samples it's just look like. i saw also: self = [super init]; if(self){...

Comment: @Brogrammer: The classic initializer style uses `if ((self = [super init])) { ... }`. This is the style that's been used for many years in Cocoa. Recently there's been a trend towards `self = [super init]; if (self) { ... }`, but this is functionally the same, although I personally think it's a waste of a line.

Comment: look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plrjQwomUtI&feature=relmfu  . here's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem with your code that I can see is you called your initializer `-initObject` for no good reason. It's not taking any parameters at all, so you really should just call it `-init` like every other parameterless initializer in the system.

As for the log output, I imagine your confusion lies in the fact that it says `<Rectangle: 0x6ab1660>`. This is perfectly normal. The default implementation of `-description` (the method that returns this output) is the name of the class of the object followed by the object's address. In other words, `-[NSObject description]` is likely to be implemented something like the following:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@: %p>",
                                      NSStringFromClass([self class]),
                                      self];
}
```

This means that instance variables of your object are not going to be printed. A number of built-in classes do print their instance variables when logged, but this was implemented specifically for that class and is not a generic mechanism. If you want to verify that your `Rectangle` object is correct, you could implement `-description` like so:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@: %p width=%d, height=%d>",
                                      NSStringFromClass([self class]),
                                      self,
                                      width,
                                      height];
}
```

Comment: Another answer that makes the rest of us redundant! I'll go back to work now... :)

Comment: thank you for help, i understand this now ; ) so, when i use init function i should to use -description.

Comment: @TomaszSzulc Not necessarily, you only need to override `description` if you want your custom class to print differently by default when passed as an argument for `stringWithFormat`. As mentioned by others you can still test those variables outside of `description`. TLDR: You don't __have__ to use `description` with your `init` functions.

Answer (score 0):

No error! Since your `Rectangle` class has no `description` method, calling `NSLog(@"%@", rect);` will return the class of the object, followed by its address in memory.

If you want to print `width` and `height` of the rectangle you may use something like:

in Rectangle.h

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject 
{
    int width;
    int height;
}
-(id)initObject;

@property int width, height;
@end
```

in Rectangle.m

```
@implementation Rectangle

@synthesize width, height;

-(id)initObject{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        height = 5;
        width = 7;
    }
    return self;
}    

@end
```

and then call

```
NSLog(@"width=%d, height=%d", [rect width], [rect height]);
```